# OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON throws an exception "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character" for valid JSON

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext

In my GeoExt client, I have the following line that retrieves JSON data from a web service into a FeatureStore:

```
var store = new GeoExt.data.FeatureStore({
        layer: route_layer,
        fields: [
            {name: "length"}
        ],
        proxy: new GeoExt.data.ProtocolProxy({
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "./php/pgrouting.php",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                    internalProjection: epsg_900913,
                    externalProjection: epsg_4326
                })
            })
        })
    });
```

When this code is executed, Firebug reports the error `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character`, even though the JSON returned by the web service is valid (I've confirmed this against http://jsonlint.com). The response header has been configured accordingly with the line `header('Content-type: application/json',true);`.

Anyone who might have encountered this issue before, please assist. I've waded around, but no luck yet.

**UPDATE:** Sample JSON output is at http://pastebin.com/LPLjBDgp. It's valid JSON, but the error `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character` persists. I've even updated my html page by adding the following line `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>` in an attempt to restrict character encoding.

Comment: Could you share your geojson file?

Comment: Does your attribute data of the feature contain any unicode (non ascii) characters?; If i remember... in php you have to use: header(....); $response = json_encode($your_data); echo $response; ...which doesnt work if you have non ascii characters.

Comment: That's a possibility. I use `json_encode()` in the php page, but I've realized I haven't specified character encoding in the html page. I'll restrict character encoding to UTF-8 and get back to you.

Comment: Or simply test the response with a simple hand constructed json string that doesnt contain any non ascii symbols

Comment: @drnextgis, I've included sample JSON file. I've also included character encoding information. Please refer to the updated post above.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is non reproducible, and OP has not provided a reproducible test case.

Comment: Could you please provide the PHP `pgrouting.php` code ?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you don't have a BOM (Byte Order Mark) in PHP file, this can break JSON.parse while being invisible in browser console.

Answer (score 0):

JSON provided above looks like pretty print json. Does you get response from web server in such formatting form? JSON.parse works with valid string, but pretty print json - is not valid for JSON.parse.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. The server returns the JSON as a string. When it's pasted in jsonlint, it's jsonlint that introduces the indentation. I also thought it would be easier to read when indented like that. But the server returns a continuous JSON string with no indentation whatsoever.

Comment: Could you share JSON in its original format.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in chrome, it will tell you what the character is when I run your data though something to make it a valid string and try to parse it in chrome I get

```
message: "Unexpected token ↵"
```

but you said the new lines aren't in the original so that message doesn't apply to you.